# Display each NSString element in an NSArray as a UIButton Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, nsstring

I am making an app that reads a text file, splits each newline into an `NSArray` element, then (hopefully) displays `UIButton`s underneath each other, whose title is the name of the array element.

For example, let's say the text file contains the following:

```
Apples
Pears
Bananas
Mangos
```

The text file (let's call it `fruit.txt`), is then read, and put into an `NSString`:

```
NSString *fruit = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/fruit.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Then split by newline into an `NSArray`:

```
NSArray *individualFruit = [fruit componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

So

```
individualFruit[0] => Apples
individualFruit[1] => Pears
individualFruit[2] => Bananas
individualFruit[3] => Mangos
```

But then, with some coding magic (probably using a for loop), we end up with something like this:

```
 -------------------
|_______Fruit_______| <- UINavigationBar
|       Apples      | <- UIButton
|___________________|
|       Pears       | <- UIButton
|___________________|
|       Bananas     | <- UIButton
|___________________|
|       Mangos      | <- UIButton
|___________________|
|                   |
|         _         |
|        ( )        |
 -------------------
```

(Excuse my horrible ascii art, it's meant to be an iPhone.)

HOWEVER…

If the user were to add another line of text to the file, for example:

```
Apples
Pears
Bananas
Mangos
Carrot
```

Then opening the app will create another button, like this:

```
 -------------------
|_______Fruit_______| <- UINavigationBar
|       Apples      | <- UIButton
|___________________|
|       Pears       | <- UIButton
|___________________|
|       Bananas     | <- UIButton
|___________________|
|       Mangos      | <- UIButton
|___________________|
|       Carrot      | <- UIButton
|___________________|
|        ( )        |
 -------------------
```

And removing a line from the text file will remove the corresponding button.

Is this possible?

Comment: Nothing, I'm stuck

Comment: How many buttons do you expect? If a small (<12) fixed number is expected, use a UIStackView otherwise the UITableView solution is probably best.

Comment: UITableView is the best solution as said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible and it should be quite simple - I would use this approach:

1. Add a tableView to your UIViewController

This will allow you to have scrolling buttons if the number of elements is too big. It also means that you can change the cell and this effect will be applied to all your buttons. If you are considering add them manually then don't - imagine if your array has 1000 fruit in it - they are not going to fit on the screen without scrolling.

2. Create a custom cell

Create a custom cell and place a UIButton in the middle of it. You can then initialise the button in cellForRowAtIndex to set the title of the button

```
// Swift
let title = individualFruit[indexPath.row] as! String
cell.button.setTitle(title for: .normal)

// Obj-C
NSString * title = individualFruit[indexPath.row];
[cell.button setTitle: title];
```

If you are not sure about creating a custom cell then look it up on Stackoverflow - it is not hard and there are a lot of resources available.

3. Update tableView when you add or remove

To do this you need to ensure the numberOfRowsForSection is linked to your array:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return individualFruit.count
}
```

Now when you add and remove you can just reload the tableView and it will update the tableView.

```
tableView.reloadData()
[tableView reloadData];
```

If you want it to look slightly nicer then maybe work out some functionality with insert and remove cell ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)) but this is beyond the scope of the question.

4. Link up the buttons

Depending on how you want to access your button press you have a number of options.

a) Deal with it in the CustomTableCellClass which you created and have a button clicked action.
b) Add a tag to the UIButtons (the index in the array) and then add a target in the cellForRowAtIndex. Then when you click a button the target method will be called and you can check the tag on the sender to calculate the index of the button and hence the title in the array.

Note: This again is slightly beyond the scope of the question as it has not explicitly been asked but why have a button that is not going to be pressed.

This functionality is all using very basic and core iOS functionality. The code I have written is all sudo code and should not be copy-pasted in - instead you should read and understand the concepts and then build the functionality yourself. If you have uncertainties I am happy to edit the answer to make it more clear.